# jetty org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

Tags: jsp, jetty, embedded-jetty

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP

i use the embedded jetty

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:610)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.<init>(Validator.java:516)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1854)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:221)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:374)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:351)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:595)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:368)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:386)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:330)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:112)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:856)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:754)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: In the stack trace there must be some more information about the cause of the exception. Please see if you cand find and add that too.

Comment: There should be more logs indicating what file caused the issue, along with a line number indicating where in that file the compilation failed.

Answer (score 0):

@Joakim Erdfelt
There is nothing else, I'm just accessing a JSP。this is my code：

```
 Server server = new Server();
          ServerConnector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
    connector.setPort(8080);
    server.addConnector(connector);
    WebAppContext context1 = new WebAppContext();  
    context1.setDescriptor("./webContent/WEB-INF/web.xml");     
    context1.setResourceBase("./webContent");  
    context1.setContextPath("/java_web_test");  
    context1.setParentLoaderPriority(true);  
    server.setHandler(context1);  
    try {
        server.start();
    } catch (Exception e) {
    ......
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem first check your code
if you have any error on specific line then it is
because of that particular line error.

else
you need to add a jar file to your project lib
and then restart your localhost server